# How to control Boundary conditions after integrating over piecewise function?

Tags: output-formatting

The following code

```
Assuming[-1 < t < 1 && Element[a, Reals], 
 FullSimplify[
  Integrate[
   Piecewise[{{(1 + x)/(1 + t), -1 < x < t}, 
              {(1 - x)/(1 - t),  t < x < 1}, 
              {0,                True}}], 
   {x, -1, a}]]]
```

will result in
$$
\begin{cases}
 1 & a>1 \\
 \frac{(a+1)^2}{2 (t+1)} & a>-1\land a<t \\
 \frac{t+1}{2} & a=t \\
 \frac{(a-1)^2}{2 (t-1)}+1 & a>t\land a\leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

By the assumptions above, that's the same as:

$$
\begin{cases}
 1 & a\ge 1 \\
 \frac{(a+1)^2}{2 (t+1)} & a>-1\land a\leq t \\
 \frac{(a-1)^2}{2 (t-1)}+1 & a>t\land a< 1
\end{cases}
$$

which is the form I'd prefer.
Is there a way to automatically tell mathematica to do that?

The reason I want the second form is, that I'd need to integrate the output once again and in the first form, it would result in weird behavior, suddenly unnecessarily special-casing for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or things like that.

(Note that there is no case for $a\leq -1$. That case gets auto-handled by Mathematica as $\{0,True\}$ and doesn't show up when you use the \TeXFormat command)

Comment: How general a solution do you need? In the example, for instance, just eliminating the equality will do the trick, as in `% /. {y_, x_Equal} -> {y, False}`, but in more general situations this might be incorrect.

Comment: @whuber What I really want is a solution that will work for the outer-most cases all the time (which will always be something<x<-1 or somethinng>x>1) which I want to turn to x<=-1 or x>=1 respectively, and additionally, I want to get rid of any single point definitions: What I'm doing is guaranteed to be continuous and won't need such things. Beyond that I might need some more but I'll have to see if anything weird happens, in which case I'll come back if it's not clear to me how to extend a solution that may be given here.

Comment: @whuber sometimes the formating of the conditions will also be messed up, having something depending on more variables in the middle, rather than just plain x, like something<2x-t<something or stuff like that. So the simplest form of pattern-matching probably won't cut it if I can't also automate a cleanup of all cases so they become something < x < something or similar...